How to query all fields of a document with nested fields in OpenSearch (or Elasticsearch)?
I'm currently using version 2.17.1 and referring to this official documentation. OpenSearch - Query DSL - Joining Queries - Nested query - Multi-level nested queries.
Using this, I'm able to query for results where all terms must match in a single nested item.
But after introducing the nested fields, I'm no longer able to just search in every single field in the whole document with a simple string query like "(John) AND (Jane)".
Is there a way to query in a list of items where all terms must match in a single item to return the parent where necessary, but still be able to query for the terms all over the document?
--------- Update: Long version -----------
Still referring to the official documentation found here: OpenSearch - Query DSL - Joining Queries - Nested query - Multi-level nested queries as this matches one part of my requirements.
Let's say I've a document like this one:
  "patient": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "relationship": "mother",
        "phone": "5551111"
      },
      {
        "name": "Joe Doe",
        "relationship": "father",
        "phone": "5552222"
      }
    ]
  }

When I search for 'jane' and 'father' I don't expect to find this document, because although both terms are present, they are in different items in the contracts list.
I only expect to find it when the terms match within one item, like when searching for 'jane' and 'mother'.
As far as I understand it, to be able to query for patients where my search terms must match in a single 'contact', I've to declare them as type 'nested' like:
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "patient": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "contacts": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "relationship": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "phone": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

Using this mapping and a nested query like:
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "patient",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "patient.contacts",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "patient.contacts.relationship": "mother" } },
                { "match": { "patient.contacts.name": "Jane" } }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

I get exactly that behavior.
But I lose the possibility to just query over the whole document with a string query like:
   "query": {
     "query_string": {
       "query": "(John) AND (5552222)"
     }
   }
/* 'John' as property of root object of type patient and
   '5552222' as property of one of the contact's properties */

Before I introduced the nested field type, such a query would find the document just fine which is the second part of the requirement because sometimes I know which term belongs to which field and can go for the nested query, but other times I don't and therefor can't use them and want to fallback to a search over all fields of the document.
Is this possible? Is maybe the nested type the wrong approach? Is using the nested type correct but I need something other than a string query?
Thank you, kopi

I assume you just need a boolean query but not sure. https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/compound/bool/
If the bool query is not what you are looking for, can you give an example of what exactly you want to search?

@MusabDogan, I updated my question with more detailed information. Thank you for your interest.

Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm adding my suggestion as an answer.

You can use copy_to to do this
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/field-types/mapping-parameters/copy-to/
it is since Elasticsearch  version 6 so should work in OpenSearch 1.3
this will inflate the disk utilization of course but allow for free textual search like you had before

To search multiple fields at once, especially with a single query, it'd be better to normalize the data by keeping them on the same level. To do that, you can enrich the data. Here is my suggestion:

Keep one doc per patient and save it as text field.
Have multiple contact per patient as nested field to secure the relation in each sub-fields.


PUT _ingest/pipeline/add_patient_name
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_temp_patient_name",
        "value": "{{patient.name}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "patient.contacts",
        "processor": {
          "set": {
            "field": "_ingest._value.patient_name",
            "value": "{{_temp_patient_name}}"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "_temp_patient_name"
      }
    }
  ]
}


PUT hospital
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "patient": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "contacts": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "relationship": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "phone": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.default_pipeline": "add_patient_name"
  }
}


PUT hospital/_doc/1
{
  "patient": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "relationship": "mother",
        "phone": "5551111"
      },
      {
        "name": "Joe Doe",
        "relationship": "father",
        "phone": "5552222"
      }
    ]
  }
}


GET hospital/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "patient.contacts",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "*",
          "query": "John AND 5552222"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



Thank you @MusabDogan. That looks very interesting and I definitely learned something new about pipelines and processors :)
In the meantime I realized that there are two parameters which I can set for nested fields. include_in_parent and include_in_root (https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/field-types/supported-field-types/nested/#parameters).
Using either one of them, I get the kind of behavior I wanted as all the nested properties are flattened into the parent or root document.

You're welcome @kopi_b. Happy to hear it helped you use case. In addition, thanks for sharing the doc, I just learned a new thing too :)
